# Three.js PointLight not working

Tags: javascript, 3d

I have been testing a bit with the Three.js library, took a look at the docs, and came up with a simple script that creates a box. Everything fine up till here. Then I tried to add a light, and it just didn't light up my box.
The script:

```
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x000066 });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 0.9));
    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 100);
    pointLight.position.x = 0;
    pointLight.position.y = 10;
    pointLight.position.z = 0;
    scene.add(pointLight);
    scene.add(cube);
    camera.position.z = 4;
    camera.position.y = 1;
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    animate();
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        render();

    }
    function render(){
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

How it shows:
[image: This is the result]

help!

Comment: `MeshBasicMaterial` doesn't support lighting.use other material types such as `Lambert`,`Phong`

Comment: Ok, I'll try that

Comment: I changed it to `MeshLambertMaterial` and it worked!!

Comment: Yes, I think it is a duplicate question...

Comment: Do I delete it?

Comment: you can but you don't need to.you can mark it as duplicate